# How to add 1-time-free proposals to my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x

I have a website (python3 + django1.8 + jQuery + IIS8) where people purchase a service. I would like to created some a 1-time-free proposals that can be sent to various people.

My thought was to add a URL param that will hold a coupon-id and if it is found then the service will be free.

My quick and dirty straightforward solution would be adding a JS/jquery script with an array e.g.

```
var myCoupons =  [ [coupon_id_1, expiration_date_1] , 
                   [coupon_id_2, expiration_date_2] , 
                   [coupon_id_3, expiration_date_3] ...
                 ]
```

When user enters my webpage, my jQuery will check if URL param = one of the coupon_id, and if expiration date is ok and then make the price of the service free.

*p.s. Yeah, I know that it is not safe and can be spooked by looking at the code, but I dont care, since developing it on the server side (I feel like) will take more time than loosing 1$ if someone spooks my code.*

**My question is**: Is there a solution to do it in a more elegant way?

Comment: a jQuery module that does what exactly?

Comment: Enables me to give 1-time-free offers. (I have described my own thought how to do it, but maybe there is a "more elegant" way to do it...)

Comment: First I think there's a lot of ways you can make this work, there is no specific jquery plugin that does this specific thing.Why not just use a normal database entries check the date that is attached it will be the same just hold the list in the database?

Comment: Thanks @Yousef_Shamshoum. This would require server side coding, adding DB (which I do not use now) and extra development time. It would also requre each time entering  to DB and adding new recording. (I feel that this would be an overkill....)

Comment: No, there is no jQuery module that is designed to specifically enable people to give 1-time-free-offers.

Comment: Thanks. please see my edited question